# Dokku start Mongo after reboot

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mean-stack, dokku

I've been playing around with Dokku on a server and using it to deploy MEAN apps. I really like it, but my one concern is that after a server reboot (or crash), Dokku doesn't restart the Mongo service. I manually have to go in and `dokku mongodb:start` and then `dokku MYAPP deploy` to get it to reconnect. Otherwise I get a bad gateway error.

Thanks for any tips! I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: Nowadays this is `dokku mongo:start <db-name>` (instead of dokku mongodb:start quoted above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug in the dokku-mongodb plugin.](https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-mongodb-plugin/issues/35) Dokku itself uses an Upstart script to start on boot. It is installed to `/etc/init/dokku-redeploy.conf` and looks like this:

```
description "Dokku app redeploy service"
start on filesystem and started docker
script
  sleep 2 # give docker some time
  sudo -i -u dokku /usr/local/bin/dokku ps:restartall
end script
```

I'd suggest using something similar, perhaps:

```
description "Dokku MongoDB plugin redeploy service"

start on started dokku-redeploy
stop on runlevel [!12345]

setuid dokku
setgid dokku

exec /usr/local/bin/dokku mongodb:start
pre-stop exec /usr/local/bin/dokku mongodb:stop
```